# How can I change the width of a selector if I am using uniform.default jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to change the width of a single selector and I'm having a ton of issues because I'm using the uniform.default jQuery plugin.

I have a selector for just a single digit, and it is really frustrating that I cannot set the width of this selector. Is there anyway I can do this?

Thanks,
Ringo

Comment: show us the HTML+ jQuery selector. fiddle would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is a digit like so?

```
455 { width: 100px; }
```

No can do. It has to be prefixed by a letter.